# Issue in the breadcrumb displaying in the Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop, breadcrumbs, prestashop-1.6

I'm building a PrestaShop tend and I have a problem with the breadcrumb. It seems to show all categories and subcategories, not only indicated. Like shows in the photo.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No one has any idea? It's so important for me. Please helps me!

Comment: I had this issue when the nleft and nright columns in ps_category was not calculated. Fixed it by editing a category manually in the backend, which forces recalulation of the nested-set.